# iOS: cellForRowAtIndexPath not called after rest call response

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, rest

My code makes a rest call to update data on the server and my response callback attempts to update a tableview content:

```
- (void)respondWithPickUniqueCodeOk:(NSDictionary *)jsonDict
 {
     if ( [self isResponseInError:jsonDict] )
     {
         [self processScanningErrors:jsonDict];
     }
     else
     {
       [self loadTable];
     }
 }
```

loadtable makes another rest call to the server:

```
-(void)loadTable
{
    [[NetworkManager sharedManager] networkApiGetLinesForDocument:currentDocument withDelegate:self];
}

the response callback from this call updates the data array and reloads the table

- (void)respondWithGetLinesOk:(NSDictionary *)jsonDict
{
    [lines removeAllObjects];

    if ( [self isResponseInError:jsonDict] )
    {
        [self checkErrors:jsonDict];
    }
    else
    {
         ...lines array updated

            [table reloadData];


    }
}
```

My problem is that numberOfRowsInSection etc is always called but cellForRowAtIndexPath never is.  It is not a threading issue as I have checked that all this is on the main thread.

Comment: does your `numberOfRowsInSection` return 0?

Comment: Is your table visible on screen with a non-zero size?